# Firefox doesn't render Dravidian scripts (Telugu, Tamil, etc.) in 16.04

Tags: firefox

I upgraded to 16.04 and all Dravidian pages (in Kannada, Malayalam, Tamil and Telugu) have become blank rectangles. No problem with the Nagari-based North Indian languages (Hindi, etc.). The other laptop still running Ubuntu 15.10 has no such problem. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Make sure these languages are checked in language support in your system settings

Comment: That worked, Mostafa Ahangarha: Thank you! But Hindi is not checked, and yet renders fine. Still, the immediate issue is resolved.

Comment: Most welcome. Please accept the answer in order to close the topic

Answer (score 5):

In my case it fixed just after installing indic fonts. You can install that specific package by

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
```

or even shorter

```
sudo apt install fonts-indic
```

Comment: This helped, commenting for better reach. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Settings and in Language Support check the mentioned languages

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this link [How to Set telugu fonts clearly in mozilla firefox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJCM2A4FPiY)

you can add any language